# Firebase Authentication Email Not Registering

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having trouble getting emails and passwords to register into my Firebase database. The code runs smoothly, but when I segue out of the page from signing up the user, the email does not show up in my Firebase database. My code is below.

```
@IBAction func FinalNext(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if let email = EmailSignUp.text, let password = PasswordSignUp.text {
        
        FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
            if authResult != nil {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUpToFeed", sender: self)
            }
                else {
                    print("There was an error")
                }
            }
        
    
}
}
```

Thank you!

I've made sure that it is configured and everything... it works to login a user if i manually input that user into my Firebase database. I am just unable to have the email and password registered into the database from my project.

Comment: Your code isn't actually writing anything to a database.  It's just creating a user in Firebase Authentication (which is not a database).  Are you saying that the user doesn't show up in the Auth console?

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, sorry about that. I meant to say that the user does not show up in the console

Comment: No, you don't need to save login and password to a database.  I've tested it myself with an old sample project that I created two years ago.  You do need to enable Keychain sharing, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the firebase console and in the authentication page, under the Sign-In method, allow email

[image]